# Button click not firing

Tags: asp.net

I was wondering why my button has stopped firing its event..

Here is my markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" BackColor="#444444" BorderStyle="None"  ForeColor="White" Height="40px" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Register" Width="603px"  />
```

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = txtUID.Text;
    string password = txtRegPass.Text;
    string password2 = txtRegPassConfirm.Text;
    string clientid = Convert.ToString(Session["UniqueID"]);

    if (Databasescripts.checkforExistingAccount(username) == false)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Username already taken!');", true);
    }

    else if (password != password2)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Password does not match!');", true);
    }
    else
    {
        ///Email validation page to client
        MailMessage MyMailMessage = new MailMessage();
        MyMailMessage.From = new MailAddress("noreplyasiainsph@gmail.com", "Asia Insurance Philippines");
        MyMailMessage.To.Add(txtRegEmail.Text.ToString());
        MyMailMessage.Subject = "asiainsphclaims.com- Verify Email";
        MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

        MyMailMessage.Body = "<body bgcolor=\"#F5F5F5\"><center><font face=\"Cambria\" size=2><img src=\"http://i1332.photobucket.com/albums/w609/asiainsphclaims/48880_zps3cdf1a95.jpg\" border=\"0\" alt=\"Asia Insurance (Philippines) Corporation\"/><br>";

        MyMailMessage.Body += "Account Registration Successful!<br><br>";
        MyMailMessage.Body += "Your account details are as follows:<br>";
        MyMailMessage.Body += "<br>Username: <b>" + txtUID.Text.ToString() + "</b><br>";
        MyMailMessage.Body += "<br>Password: <b>" + txtRegPass.Text.ToString() + "</b><br>";
        MyMailMessage.Body += "Click on the link below to verify your E-mail Address<br>";
        MyMailMessage.Body += "<a href=\"http://www.asiainsphclaims.com/VerifyEmail.aspx\">VERIFY NOW</a><br>";
        MyMailMessage.Body += "<br><br><br><a href=\"http://twitter.com/AsiaInsurancePH\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"http://i1332.photobucket.com/albums/w609/asiainsphclaims/Twitter_zps36d6a150.png\" border=\"0\" alt=\"Follow us on Twitter!\"></a>";
        MyMailMessage.Body += "<a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/pages/Asia-Insurance-Philippines/660815073932476\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"http://i1332.photobucket.com/albums/w609/asiainsphclaims/Facebook_zps562abd5c.png\" border=\"0\" alt=\"Like us on Facebook!\"/></a>";
        MyMailMessage.Body += "<br><br><font size=3><em>Asia Insurance (Philippines) Corporation</em></font>";
        MyMailMessage.Body += "<br>15/F Tytana Bldg. Plaza Lorenzo Ruiz Binondo, Manila, Philippines <br>Telephone: (632)241-5201 | Fax: (632)243-3216 | Email: <a href=\"mailto:aipc@asiains.com.ph\">aipc@asiains.com.ph</a>";

        SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        SMTPServer.Port = 587;
        SMTPServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("noreplyasiainsph@gmail.com", "apcAPC2013");
        SMTPServer.EnableSsl = true;

        SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage);
        Databasescripts.proceedRegister();
        Response.Redirect("RedirecttAfterAccountCreation.aspx");
    }

}
```

---

my solution:

That's it I was able to fix my own problem. I remembered that I have put a "popup div" in where the user can update its email, and I have a validation there, which in turn, its waiting an input from the user. I was able to fix this by removing the validation from the email update..

Comment: Usually there is some javascript preventing form submission. Check the browser console.

Comment: Anothing thing that I've seen happen is if the page directive is pointing to the wrong code behind.  This can happen if you copy a page in visual studio.

Comment: That's it I was able to fix my own problem. I remembered that I have put a "popup div" in where the user can update its email, and I have a validation there, which in turn, its waiting an input from the user. I was able to fix this by removing the validation from the email update..

THANKYOU ALL FOR YOUR TIME

Answer (score 0):

Try to include `CausesValidation = false`

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" BackColor="#444444" BorderStyle="None"  ForeColor="White" Height="40px" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Register" Width="603px"  />
```

Comment: So, I need more code to check it, if possbile expose all your aspx file.

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AccountRegistration.aspx.cs" Inherits="myAsiaIns.AccountRegistration" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: That's it I was able to fix my own problem. I remembered that I have put a "popup div" in where the user can update its email, and I have a validation there, which in turn, its waiting an input from the user. I was able to fix this by removing the validation from the email update..

THANKYOU ALL FOR YOUR TIME

Comment: For that I'd like to see all your aspx. Anyway post your solution to help others with the same problem. My pleasure.